# How can I put date, time, and values from radio buttons to database

Tags: php, mysql, forms, datetime, insert

I have a simple form looking like this:

```
<input class="form-control" type="date" name="date">
<input class="form-control" type="time" name="time">
```

and couple of radio buttons:

```
<input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" value="1">
```

I would like to INSERT date (Y-m-d) from datepicker, time (H:i) and value from radio button into database.

My php script looks like this:

```
$conn_servername = "localhost";
$conn_username = "root";
$conn_password = "root";
$conn_db = "restaurant";

$conn = mysqli_connect($conn_servername, $conn_username, $conn_password, $conn_db);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 



if (isset($_POST['reserv-send'])) { //<button name="reserv-send"></button>
$options = $_POST['options'];
$date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($_POST['date']));
$time = $_POST['time'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO reservations (date, time, options)
    VALUES ('$options', '$date', '$time')";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
   echo "New record created successfully";
} 
else 
{
echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
}
```

My table values in database are date for date, time for time and int for options. (I don't know if I schould set default NULL for date and time?).

I try many options but still got nothing, and the result always give me date 0000-00-00 in database.

Comment: This is a typographical error as I originally voted earlier. You mixed up your values.

Comment: This is open to an SQL injection; use a prepared statement if you don't want your database to be compromised or deleted one day. Had you used PDO with `:val` placeholders, you wouldn't have that problem regardless of the order.  *Plus*, you'd be safeguarding against injection.

Comment: Thank you! I mixed up the values indeed. I set up values properly and all works fine thanks once again.